# What is wrong with derefrencing this pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

While debugging i found that my program stops at: "cout << *ptr ; cout << "\n";" what is wrong with this code?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int *ptr = 0;
void myfun(void);

int main()
{
    void myfun();
    for(int j = 1; j < 3; j++)
    {
        ptr = ptr-j ;       
        cout << *ptr ; cout << "\n";

    }
    return(0);  
}

void myfun(void)
{
    int x[3] = {11,12,13};
    for(int i = 0; i <3; i++)
    {
        ptr = &x[i];
        ptr = ptr+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `void myfun();` does not call a function. It's a function declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the above answers and a little bit of googling I found out the exact solution to my problem: To return variable sized array from a function.

This is the code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int * myfun(void);

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = myfun();
    int len = (sizeof(ptr)/sizeof(*ptr));
    for(int j = 0; j <= len; j++)
    {
        cout << ptr[j];
    }
    return(0);  
}
int * myfun()
{
    static int x[3] = {11,12,13};
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that 's incorrect. The only reason that "works" is because the size of a pointer happens to be twice the size of an int in your environment. Also, if it _would_ have worked, what is the motivation to use "<=" in your loop instead of "<"? Try add another number to your array and see for yourself.

Comment: If the called function is responsible for deciding the size of the array, then the size of that array should also be returned from the function. One possibility would be to use an "out" argument of type size_t*. However, I would advise you to study dynamic memory allocation in order to solve this in a more generic way; i.e. malloc/free et al.

Answer (score 8):

You initialized your pointer with zero

```
int *ptr = 0;
```

which means that it is a null pointer.

Then you are applying pointer arithmetic to a null pointer. The behavior is undefined. The you are dereferencing the nonsensical pointer obtained in that way. The behavior is undefined.

Note that

```
void myfun();
```

in `main` is not a function call, it is a function declaration. A call to `myfun` (which was apparently your intent) would look as follows

```
myfun();
```

Why did you put that `void` there in your version of the code?

Comment: I got my mistake. Now i am getting 13,0,0 as my output. What should i do to get 13,12,11?

Comment: @jeniShah That is an entirely different question altogether.

Comment: In any case, myfun sets the pointer to point to a location on the stack that becomes invalid as soon as myfun exits. Furthermore, the last iteration of the loop sets the pointer to a location beyond the end of the array, which is also undefined. Then the main function subtracts a total of 6 from the pointer, which results in a position before the beginning of the now invalid array. There are just too many problems with this code to even begin to imagine what the correct version should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable ptr is a wild pointer.

Although you let the ptr porint to array x, when the myfun() finish and return the memory of x had been destory. So in the main function, ptr become wild pointer and your program will crash.

You should know that the local variable will be destoried when they are not in their scope.

Comment: "I got my mistake. Now i am getting 13,0,0 as my output. What should i do to get 13,12,11"

Although you have print the answer, it is not safe and your program have an in potential crash problem.

Answer (score 0):

main function doesn't have access to the data, as scope of the array x[3] is myfun(void). After `myfun` call (it should be `myfun();` instead of `void myfun();`), ptr will be pointing to an unallocated memory location.

To print the data in main function, you can declare the `int x[3]` as a global variable.

```
int *ptr = 0;
void myfun(void);

int x[3] = {11,12,13};

int main()
{
    int *temp_ptr;
    myfun();
    temp_ptr = ptr;
    for(int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        temp_ptr = ptr-j ;       
        cout << *temp_ptr ; cout << "\n";

    }
    return(0);  
}
```

Comment: my aim is to return values generated inside a function. and i also dont know the length of array in advance.